# Combination and Solutions: The Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When one says combine, they generally mean combine numbers or variables that are alike (i.e.: $4x$ and $3x$, $2xy$ and $22xy$). My issue is with what happens in between the solution set with the following problem.

$$(2x - 3y + 4z) - (5x + 2y - 3z) + (4x - 5y + 2z) =$$

Given that finding the like terms is relatively easy, I'd like to know what I do after I've decided "Okay, I now know what the like terms are." Now how do I go about jotting the rest down and completing the problem?

Comment: First, complain about the mismatched parenthesis.  Without the right side there is no solution set.  You indicate no problem combining the three terms in $x,y,$ and $z$, so what is the question?

Comment: I updated the original question. My question is as asked. "How do I go about jotting the rest down and completing the problem?"

Comment: If that's all then you get $x-10y+9z$

Answer (score 0):

So you combine $2x, -5x, 4x$ and get $x$.  You do similarly for the terms in $y$ and $z$.  The answer will be of the form $x+()y+()z$  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Basically. My main question would be what exactly do I combine? (How). 2x, 5x and 4x are similar, correct? So my next step would be what? Which numbers go into your given format x+()y+()z. Only after I've added/subtracted, or do I enter them beforehand?

Comment: You add them up.  You are using the distributive law where $2x-5x+4x=(2-5+4)x=1\cdot x=x$  Similarly you add up the coefficients on $y$ and $z$

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know which user to ask here. Is this correct? (2x − 3y + 4z) − (5x + 2y − 3z) + (4x − 5y + 2z) 
2x - 3y + 4z - 5x - 2y + 3z + 4x - 5y + 2z 
2x - 5x + 4x - 3y - 2y - 5y + 4z + 3z + 2z 
x - 10y + 9z

Comment: Somehow your equal signs disappeared, but the result is correct.

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah, that's strange.